# Is imshow and pick_event applicable?

Tags: matplotlib

Want have a color picker for shown images with MatPlotLib.
Is there a chance with the pick_event?

In the examples for pick_event always subplots() are used.
Are subplots compatible with pictures?

Thank You for answer
Erhy

Comment: If you show an image with matplotlib (via `plt.imshow`), it will reside in an axes. This axes is the subplot. So, yes, subplots are compatible with pictures.

Comment: It works only with figure objects
fig, ax = plt.imread("x.png")
results in the error: too many values to unpack
and
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(pic.shape[0],pic.shape[1]))
results in the error: not enough free memory for image buffer

Comment: Just stick to [this example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/image_demo.html) instead of mixing commands randomly.

Answer (score 0):

here my code for example which works

it is less comfortable as without subplots
because the visual front-end sends no events if the image was moved or zoomed

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import imageio

pic = np.asarray(imageio.imread("1000x1500.png")) #with width 1000 and heigh 1500
print(type(pic)) 
print("picture shape: " + str(pic.shape)) #why first value for y, second for x
print("color of point[x=999][y=1499]: " + str(pic[1499][999])) # x,y are swapped?
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1) #necessary, to get mouse events
im1 = ax.imshow(pic, picker=True)
print("ax: " + str(type(ax)) )
ax.axis([0, pic.shape[1], pic.shape[0], 0]) #to have the same axis as without subplots

def onpick(event):
    mouseevent = event.mouseevent
    x = mouseevent.xdata
    y = mouseevent.ydata
    print('x=' + str(x) + ' y=' + str(y) + ' color: ' +
         str(pic[int(y)][int(x)])) # in pic x,y are swapped !

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)

plt.show()
```